# How to create a function that converts month values into quarter using if statement in python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I need to create a function called as convert_to_qtr() that converts monthly values in the month value of data frame into quarters. Given below is the month data frame below:-

[image: month dataframe]

In the convert_to_qtr() function, we should use the following if conditions:-
• If the month input is Jan-Mar, then the function returns “Q1”
• If the month input is Apr-Jun, then the function returns “Q2”
• If the month input is Jul-Sep, then the function returns “Q3”
• If the month input is Oct-Dec, then the function returns “Q4”

Then this function should be applied to Month Dataframe provided above and a new column called as Quarter should be created that contains the quarter of each observations of months(January, Feb) etc it is aligned to .

```
quarter = 0
excl_merged['quarter'] = excl_merged[quarter] 

excl_merged
def convert_to_quarterly(excl_merged):
    if excl_merged['Month'] == 'January' &  excl_merged['Month'] == 'February' &  excl_merged['Month'] == 'March':
        print(excl_merged[quarter] == 'Q1')
    elif excl_merged['Month'] == 'April' &  excl_merged['Month'] == 'May' &  excl_merged['Month'] == 'June':
        print(excl_merged[quarter] == 'Q2')
    elif excl_merged['Month'] == 'July' &  excl_merged['Month'] == 'August' &  excl_merged['Month'] == 'September':
        print(excl_merged[quarter] == 'Q3')
    else:
        print(excl_merged[quarter] == 'Q4')
        

convert_to_quarterly(excl_merged)
```

I was not able to run the function properly and hence was getting errors

Comment: Look carefully at your if statements. The month can't be January, February, and March at the same time. Also it doesn't look like you are assigning the quarter for the month ranges anywhere ..

Comment: I am not able to do it, Can you post the solution so that I would be able to understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert_to_quarter( month):
  months = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April ', 'May', 'June', \
             'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
  return months.index[ 'month'] // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
def convert_to_quarterly(excl_merged):
    if excl_merged['Month'] in ['January', 'February', "March"]:
        excl_merged[quarter] == 'Q1'
    elif excl_merged['Month'] in ["April", "May", "June"]:
        excl_merged[quarter] == 'Q2'
    elif excl_merged['Month'] in ['July', 'August', 'September']:
        excl_merged[quarter] == 'Q3'
    elif excl_merged["Month"] in ["November", "December", "December"]:
        excl_merged[quarter] == 'Q4'
    else:
        print("Unkown month name!")
```

The main problem is that you are using an and statement.
A month can't be "Januar" and "Fabruary".

I would also recoment to use brackets when useing the & or | operator around the single bool operations.

At last i would recoment to use the in operator to test against all three values at one. It should be faster and the code is much easier to read.

Comment: I am getting the error below while trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to do something like:

```
df.Transaction_Timestamp.apply(lambda x: "Q" + str(x.quarter))
```

---

### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Transaction_Timestamp":pd.date_range("2022-01-01", periods=365),
    "Value":rng.integers(0, 100, size=365)
})

df["Qrt"] = df.Transaction_Timestamp.apply(lambda x: "Q" + str(x.quarter))

df.head()

    Transaction_Timestamp   Value   Qrt
0   2022-01-01              84      Q1
1   2022-01-02              43      Q1
2   2022-01-03              91      Q1
3   2022-01-04              29      Q1
4   2022-01-05              88      Q1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Create the function convert_to_qtr() that takes in a month (January, February, etc.) and returns the associated quarter. So if the month is January, return 1, if December, return 4, etc. For a month to be in the first quarter, for example, the month could be January **or** February **or** March. A month cannot be January and February and March at the same time, which is what your code is currently checking for. This function should also be taking in a month instead of a dataframe.
2. Apply this function to the Month column in your dataframe, and store the result in a new column called Quarter. You can do something like: `df['Quarter'] = df.Month.apply(lambda month: convert_to_qtr(month))`. This is saying: look at the month column, df.Month. Then, call the convert_to_qtr function on each value in the month column. The result is then stored as a new column in your dataframe, Quarter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [a map function in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). You need a dictionary that maps the months into quarters.

```
import pandas as pd

# an sorted list of months
list_of_months =['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

# creating a dictionary with the months and quarters
d = {}
for i, month in enumerate(list_of_months):
    d[month] = 'Q' + str(i//3+1)

# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(['Jan','Dec','Mar'],columns=['Month'])

# applying map to series
df['Month'].map(d)
```

The result looks like:

```
    Month   Quarter
0   Jan     Q1
1   Dec     Q4
2   Mar     Q1
```